# Footer problems

Tags: table-footer

I am currently trying to add links to my footer so that they are displayed from left to right inside the footer. Currently they are being displayed in a list going down the page.

Comment: Displayed as a list, do you mean, that they have ol pr ul html structure? Please paste your code, so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

try ol instead of li. this should do it.